# Book recommendation on distributed computing concepts used in Cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra, distributed-computing

What book would you recommend on the distributed computing concepts/database internals used with Cassandra?

A list of concepts and defintions are listed at [this Cassandra glossary](http://io.typepad.com/glossary.html#gls-readrepair)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't delve much into the concepts, note that there is an O'Reilly [book dedicated to Cassandra](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920010852). It's OK, but not up to the usual O'Reilly standard in some places. The explanation of the detailed architecture is rather chaotic and hard to follow.

Comment: So it's not a great book?

Comment: Not great, IMO, but I haven't seen anything better yet.

Answer (score 5):

Since Cassandra is a mix between Amazon Dynamo and Google BigTable I suggest you go ahead and read the research papers about these systems:

- [Dynamo: Amazon’s Highly Available Key-value Store](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html)
- [Bigtable: A Distributed Storage System for Structured Data](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html)

Read the Dynamo paper first. Concepts like Quorum, Read Repair, [Eventual Consistency](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2008/12/eventually_consistent.html), etc. are explained very well there. After that read the Big Table paper. If you don't understand some of the terms used in these papers go ahead an google for them.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the nosql summer reading list for a bunch of good papers on nosql concepts.  http://nosqlsummer.org/papers

Comment: Link in the answer is dead